Why are all the ec2 that are in the auto scaling group not assigned to the target group after running the follow ansible command?
    - name: Create Auto Scaling Group 
      amazon.aws.autoscaling_group:
      name: "asg"
      launch_template:
        launch_template_name: "launch-template"
      health_check_period: 60
      health_check_type: ELB
      replace_all_instances: true
      min_size: 1
      max_size: 3
      desired_capacity: 2
      region: us-east-1
      replace_all_instances: true
      target_group_arns: "{{ target_group.target_group_arn }}"
      vpc_zone_identifier: ["{{ private_subnet_info1.subnets[0].subnet_id }}", "{{ private_subnet_info2.subnets[0].subnet_id }}"]
      wait_for_instances: false
      wait_timeout: 1800

I can see that is correct in web console after this but no instances are in the target group, so to fix I have to unassign it in the web console and then re-assign it.
After running the ec2 will launch and be assigned to the target group.

What do you mean by "unassign it in the web"? Is it showing in the Target Group and you remove it from the Target Group and you add it back to the Target Group? In that case, what do you mean by "no instances are in the target group"? Or are you saying that they were in the Target Group but they weren't receiving/processing traffic?

What do you mean by "unassign it in the web"? https://console.aws.amazon.com/
Is it showing in the Target Group and you remove it from the Target Group and you add it back to the Target Group? Yes
In that case, what do you mean by "no instances are in the target group"? If I run the ansible script, I would expect that the auto scaling group would launch 2 instances, it doesn't. In the web console under auto scaling , there is a section "Load balancing" , so I remove the same target group and readd it, then the instance are under the load balance correctly.
